# Jquery : 'types' can only be used in a .ts file

Tags: javascript, leaflet, marker

I am working on Jquery project using Leaflet map . My project is getting data json coordinates for flights position . My code below is working fine , but the problem is l have repeat markers on map while data is updating . l did some steps to remove previous markers position then shows new markers position, but l have error  `'types' can only be used in a .ts file.`

markers repeated on map while data is updating

[image: markers repeated on map while data is updating]

My code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    var heading ;
coords: L.Marker[]
    var type ;
    //      map initializing   

        var coords = [33,44]; // the geographic center of our map
        var zoomLevel = 6 // the map scale. 
        var map = L.map('map').setView(coords, zoomLevel);
        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/transport-dark/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: 'Map data &copy;',
                maxZoom: 18
        }).addTo(map);


    //     Aircraft data

        setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', {
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    timeout: 5000
                    }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

              // Error is here ------------ under marker //
               coords ? coords.forEach((marker:marker) => {
                                marker.remove();
                              }) : '';

                 coords = [];

                         Object.keys(data)
                            .map(key => data[key])
                            .map((position) => ({
                                    lat: position[1],
                                    lng: position[2],
                                    callSign: position[13],
                                    heading: position[3],
                                    AircraftType: position[8]
                            })).filter(position => position.lat && position.lng && position.callSign 
                                    && position.heading
                                    && position.AircraftType).forEach(i => {
                                            console.log(i.lat, i.lng, i.heading)

                           coords.push(  new L.Marker([i.lat, i.lng], {
                                        icon: new L.DivIcon({
                                          html: ` <div style="width:120px;";>
                                          <div class="temp-${i.heading}  ${type}"></div>
                                        <span style="color:white;background-color: midnightblue;margin: 4px;padding: 4px;border-radius: 3px;">
                                         ${i.callSign}
                                        </span
                                        ></div>`

                                        })

                                      }).addTo(marker))

                        })
        },5000)


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using a type here:
`coords ? coords.forEach((marker:marker) => {`
The first marker is your variable and the second one after the colon is the type used in TypeScrypt. Try removing the colon and the marker there.

```
coords ? coords.forEach((marker) => {
```

Comment: l have errro under `coords: L.Marker[]` `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ']'`

Comment: `coords: L.Marker[]` this might not be needed at all or should be just `var coords;`

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: marker.remove is not a function` . So i have to use `coords: L.Marker[]` to remove markers

Comment: That's probably caused by the fact that you have no markers created but your coords have values so create the first marker before the ajax call if you have the coords.